# Load a Gif without the animation

Tags: java

I am currently using image icons to load the gifs onto a JFrame but when loading a couple hundred it takes too much ram space so I just want to load a still image of the gif instead so it doesn't take up to much space.

Comment: I guess you could just read the first frame, but if you don't want animation, why do you have animated gifs in the first place? (You also may want to read [ask].)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly which type of program you're into but i'll assume that you want to have more dynamic space to give you an answer. If you're looking to reduce space ram, you could use JPEG's format instead of GIF's one. Make the images static attributes to the class to just load once those gifs; think about them as a resources class.
If you want to keep GIF format from the images and you want them to stop moving, you can edit loop flag that's inside gif's file to stop looping for movement. Use this [page](https://ezgif.com/loop-count) to set off that loop flag.
I hope this helps you out!